# How to record / splice FLV clips?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video, record, splice

I'm working on an application for a company that wants to create a service for their users.  This company currently offers videos that are around 1.5 hours in length, and the service they want to integrate is the ability for the user to 'record' clips of this larger video to create, essentially, a highlight reel.  The end result of this service would be a 3 minute video of the user's favorite parts of a huge 1.5 hour long video.  Make sense?

For the sake of simplicity in asking my question, imagine the user interaction to be very basic.  The user watches the video, he/she can press 'record' to record a clip of the master video.  Now... I'm already aware of FLVslicer by Thibault at ByteArray, but I've thought surely there is some other approach to recording / splicing / merging FLV clips than just this guy's framework.

And so finally, my question is: do any of you have insight as to how I might investigate the best way to create this functionality aside from using FLVslicer?  I can't seem to find any other route for "recording" clips from videos like this.  *(EDIT: Vi gave a fantastic response about how to accomplish this outside of the Flash app, but my curiosity is still aimed at if this can be done purely within Flash.  High five though, Vi!)*

Thanks for your input,

Blake

Answer (score 2):

For example, use ffmpeg/mkvtools:

```
ffmpeg -i video.flv -ss 00:00:05 -t 00:00:10 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -y test1.mkv
           input file    start time   length
ffmpeg -i video.flv -ss 00:00:45 -t 00:00:10 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -y test2.mkv
mkvmerge -o test.mkv test1.mkv + test2.mkv
```

test.mkv will contain 0:05-0:15+0:45-0:55 from video.flv. No re-encoding => no quality loss.

But if you have the source video not encoded as flv it's may better to prepare the video from raw first and then encode to flv as the last step. It is slower, but more correct and flexible.

Comment: Wow Vi, I really appreciate that!  My original question was aimed at accomplishing that entirely from within Flash, and I am still curious about that.  However, we will be using ffmpeg to convert raw video to FLV so that the Flash app can manage the video well, so your idea may become a very plausible solution!  Thank you very much!

Comment: It's better to splice raw video/mpeg first and encode to flv at the last step. Joining splices extracted from flv is weird thing. For example, you can't convert it from mkv to flv with ffmpeg easily and when playing it is not smooth between segments.

Answer (score 1):

have you checked FLVSlicer by Thibault Imbert : http://www.bytearray.org/?p=955
it seems to do ( more or less :) ) what you want.
cheers

Comment: Yes I have!  I mentioned it in my question.  Thanks though.

Comment: oops shame on me :S
another way is to create a flv file on the fly with Lee felacra's flv encoder: http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/simpleflvwriteras-as3-class-to-create-flvs/
I wouldn't recommend that though for it's far too CPU intensive & memory expensive